# Leveraging the v-for loop for places outside the v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

While looping on array of `sales` , i need to capture the object of which `salesPerson === "bar"` and print its `sellValue` outside the `v-for` block.

Of course i can't access the array in hard-coded way. i have to assume that the position of the object i'm looking for is random.

also, i can't add another loop on top of the one loop that already exist here. (v-for is a loop obviously).

i need way to do achieve it.

here is an example component:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <!-- i need to print here the sellValue of 'bar' -->
    <p v-for="(sell,index) in sales"
      :key="index">{{sell.sellValue}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data() {
    return {
      sales: [
        {
          salesPerson: 'foo',
          sellValue: 1
        },
        {
          salesPerson: 'bar',
          sellValue: 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't understand why do you want to achieve that in the html and not in the js with iteration on the sales object, any specific reason?

Comment: @AminJafari if i iterate on the object using javascript for finding `sellValue===bar` , and then using v-for to print all the elements, i am looping on the same object twice.

Comment: @acdcjunior - a typo. fixed.

Comment: I'm afraid it's inevitable unless you want to write a method to pass each object to on the iteration then check the condition inside the method and if it passes then assign it to a variable, which would get ugly and very hard to understand and I personally wouldn't recommend it and I'll take the risk of having to iterate on the same array twice.

Comment: This is a micro-optimization. Forget it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a custom HTML tag (not registered as a component for Vue), it's quite "ugly" but that is the only solution I could think of (beware of Vue's warnings if not disabled) :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <uglyTag v-for="(sell,index) in sales" :key="index">
      {{sell[ sell.findIndex( e=>e.salesPerson==="bar" ) ].sellValue}}
      <p>{{ sell.sellValue }}</p>
    </uglyTag>
  </div>
</template>
```

Another solution would be to rethink the construction of your data so you could have (but still needs the uglyTag method) :

```
data(){
  return {
    salesTitle: 2,
    sales: [
      {
        salesPerson: 'foo',
        sellValue: 1
      },
      {
        salesPerson: 'bar',
        sellValue: 2
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <uglyTag v-for="(sell,index) in sales" :key="index">
      {{ salesTitle }}
      <p>{{ sell.sellValue }}</p>
    </uglyTag>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I didn't understand the question correctly, but you are still in the same scope of your component. Why don't you add a getter for the value you are interested in and display it where you want.

```js
Vue.component('my-template', {
  template: '    <div id="app">\
      <!-- i need to print here the sellValue of \'bar\' -->\
   <p>{{ saleValue }}</p>\
      <p v-for="(sell,index) in sales" :key="index">{{sell.sellValue}}</p>\
    </div>',
  data: function() {
    return {
      sales: [{
        salesPerson: 'foo',
        sellValue: 1
      }, {
        salesPerson: 'bar',
        sellValue: 2
      }]
    }
  },
 computed: {
  saleValue: function() {
   return this.sales.filter(function(val) {
    return val.salesPerson === 'bar';
   })[0].sellValue;
  }
 }
});

var vm = new Vue({
 el: '#vm',
 data: {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="vm">
  <my-template></my-template>
</div>
```